# Chain rule on gradient of two vectors (Momentum Equation)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, chain-rule, gradient-flows

I am confused about the application of the chain rule with the following equation:

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot (\rho \mathbf V \mathbf V)$$ where: 
$\mathbf V  = u \hat {\mathbf i} +v \hat{\mathbf j} + w \hat{\mathbf k}$ and $\rho $ is denoting density, a scalar quantity.

I am confused with the expansion of this once I have applied the chain rule and what the end result would look like.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is $\mathbf V \mathbf V$ defined? That part seems unclear to me. Is it supposed to equal $u^2 \hat {\mathbf i} +v^2 \hat{\mathbf j} + w^2 \hat{\mathbf k}$?

Comment: Where do you see the chain rule (it looks like product rule to me), and *what* does $\mathbf V\mathbf V$ mean? If it's the outer product of the vectors, how are you taking divergence?

Comment: @TedShifrin the definition I suggested (piecewise multiplication) *is* a vector. Look again! ;-)  (clearly it wouldn't work as a dot product)

Comment: @Time4Tea, my sloppiness, sorry. I actually believe it's the tensor product or outer product. What you've written down is not in the least well-defined (independent of coordinate system).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the problem with distinct vectors.
$$\eqalign{
\nabla\cdot(\rho\,ab)
 &= (\nabla\rho)\cdot ab + \rho(\nabla\cdot a)b + \rho\,a\cdot(\nabla b) \\
}$$
Each term in the product is differentiated according the usual rule. The only vector consideration is to keep the dot product between the $\nabla$-operator and the $a$-vector.

When $a=b=v,\,$ the result can be written (with fewer parentheses) as
$$\eqalign{
\nabla\cdot(\rho\,vv)
 &= vv\cdot\nabla\rho + \rho v\,\nabla\cdot v + \rho\,v\cdot\nabla v \\
}$$